# VB.Net: Get Cell Address from Row and Column

Tags: excel, vb.net, for-loop, range, cell

I know this question has been asked before, but I have tried answers to both of them and neither have worked for me..

Current Code:

```
Dim aString As String
Dim address As String
For Each thisTriangle In triangleArray
    drawTriangle(rowToDrawIn, thisTriangle.getMarkedCell)
    aString = String.Format("Activity Name: {0}", thisTriangle.getActivityDescription)

    //here is where I am trying to get the address
    address = xlWorkSheet.Cells.Address(rowToDrawIn, thisTriangle.getMarkedCell)
    xlWorkSheet.Range(address).AddComment(aString)
Next
```

As you can see, I'm attempting to get the address and then put a comment in that address. I am receiving a runtime error when this code is run. `thisTriangle.getMarkedCell` returns an int as the column number and `rowToDrawIn` is the row number.

Any and all help is much appreciated.

Comment: might be helpful to include details of the runtime error and also a sample of the data involved.

Comment: If you have the row number and column number, you can use `.Cells(row, col)` instead of `.Range(address)`.

Comment: @blackwood are you saying doing something like this `xlWorkSheet.Cells(rowToDrawIn, thisTriangle.getMarkedCell)` because that doesn't work sadly. I thought about that as well

Comment: what's the error message/ inner exception?

Comment: If `rowToDrawIn` is the row number and `thisTriangle.getMarkedCell` is the column number, would expect that to work.

Comment: @blackwood it won't even let me add on `.addComment` to that code bit

Comment: @cyboashu the error message is of type `System.ArgumentException`

Comment: Do you already have comment in that cell.?

Comment: @cyboashu no I do not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `rowToDrawIn` and `thisTriangle.getMarkedCell` are both positive ints.

Your fault is here `Cells.Address`. If you pass `Cells.Address(1,2)` you are expecting to get `$B$1` but actually you get `$1:$10485761` and now you are attempting add comments to this range and hence the argument error.

**Cells.Address(1, 2) !=  Cells(1, 2).Address**

Change this

```
  address = xlWorkSheet.Cells.Address(rowToDrawIn, thisTriangle.getMarkedCell)
    xlWorkSheet.Range(address).AddComment(aString)
```

To

```
xlWorkSheet.Cells.(rowToDrawIn, thisTriangle.getMarkedCell).Comment.Delete
xlWorkSheet.Cells.(rowToDrawIn, thisTriangle.getMarkedCell).AddComment(aString)
```

Comment: I see where you are coming from, but I am still getting a System.NullReferenceException and it's saying Object variable or With block variable not set